# How to simplify repeated functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, simplify

I'm new to programming and trying to simplify some jquery/javascript code but I'm not having much success. I tried to adapt the solution found here: [jQuery Simplify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11911551/jquery-simplify)

...but again, no success.

Here's my jquery code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#hide01").click(function(){
$(".content01").hide();
});

$("#show01").click(function(){
$("p").hide();
$(".content01").show();
});

$("#hide02").click(function(){
$(".content02").hide();
});

$("#show02").click(function(){
$("p").hide();
$(".content02").show();
});

});
</script>
```

And the HTML:

```
<button id="hide01">Hide</button>
<button id="show01">Show</button>

<button id="hide02">Hide</button>
<button id="show02">Show</button>

<p class="content01">Content 01</p>

<p class="content02">Content 02</p>
```

This solution is working but I need something like 40 buttons / blocks of content...

Anyone can help? Thanks!

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com please

Comment: whats the different between codereview and stackoverflow?

Comment: use CSS class attributes; give the hide buttons a class and the show button a different class. Give each of the button (show/hide) a data-val that is equal to its corresponding id

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would change the HTML to this:

```
<button class="btn_hide" data-id="01">Hide</button>
<button class="btn_show" data-id="01">Show</button>

<button class="btn_hide" data-id="02">Hide</button>
<button class="btn_show" data-id="02">Show</button>

<p id="content01">Content 01</p>
<p id="content02">Content 02</p>
```

Then your jQuery can be:

```
$(".btn_hide").click(function() {
    $("#content"+this.getAttribute("data-id")).hide();
});
$(".btn_show").click(function() {
    $("p").hide();
    $("#content"+this.getAttribute("data-id")).show();
});
```

Comment: Instead of `this.getAttribute()`, you could use jQuery's [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data2), for consistency if nothing else. Or just give the buttons actual `id`s?

Comment: @ajp15243 Using an actual `id` wouldn't work, since they need to be unique and the point of the `data-id` attribute is to connect multiple buttons with a single element on the page. Not to mention that using `this.getAttribute()` saves you the overhead of the jQuery functions.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Whoops didn't look too closely at the fact that `data-id`'s value was not being used uniquely. I understand that using a jQuery function would add a bit of overhead, but it would be hardly any. The way that looks easiest to read would be the best choice for clarity and future maintenance. Personally I would choose `.data()`, but the OP can make that choice for their own code.

Comment: Ok I think I understand the code but for some reason, the buttons are not working when I copy-paste it...

Comment: Oops! Ok I understand my mystake. Forgot to add the $(document).ready(function() . Everything works perfectly! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Dali Make sure to accept the answer then!

Answer (score 2):

Well with jQuery you can stack selectors IE:

```
 $("#hide01, #show01").click(function(){
    $(".content01").hide();
 });
```

But personally i would, rather than using ID's, use a class for this:

```
  <button id="hide01" class="hide">Hide</button>
  <button id="show01" class="show">Show</button>
  <button id="hide02" class="hide">Hide</button>
  <button id="show02" class="show">Show</button>
  <button id="hide03" class="hide">Hide</button>
  <button id="show04" class="show">Show</button>
```

**JS**

```
 $(".hide").click(function(){
    $(".content01").hide();
 });
 //Etc Etc..
```